# how to output the values from the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

My program is:

```
public class Vehicle {

    String colors[] = {"Red", "White", "Blue", "black", "Silver"};
    private String name;
    private String model;
    double cost_price;
    int year;
    int quantity;
    double selling_price;
    String registration_no;

    Vehicle(String name, String model, int year, double cost_price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.cost_price = cost_price;
        this.quantity = 0;
        this.selling_price = 0;
    }

    Vehicle(String name, String model, int quantity, double cost_price, String registration_no) {
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.cost_price = cost_price;
        this.selling_price = cost_price;
        this.registration_no = registration_no;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setmodel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getmodel() {
        return model;
    }

    public double calSellingPrice(int markup) {

        return cost_price + ((cost_price * markup) / 100);
    }

    public int updateQuantity(int amount) {

        return quantity;
    }

    public String tostring() {
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
}

class Vehicletest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2011, 250000);
        v1 = new Vehicle("Ferrari", "Enzo", 6, 250000, "PK07LVD");
        Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle("Audi", "R8", 2008, 550000);
        v2 = new Vehicle("Audi", "R8", 9, 550000, "ADDY104");
        Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle("RangeRover", "Evoque", 2010, 578000);
        v3 = new Vehicle("RangeRover", "Evoque", 3, 578000, "OHZ2692");
        Vehicle v4 = new Vehicle("Lamborghine", "Aventador", 2013, 980000);
        v4 = new Vehicle("Lamborghine", "Aventador", 5, 980000, "BB03813");
        Vehicle v5 = new Vehicle("Porsche", "Carrera", 2006, 675000);
        v5 = new Vehicle("Porsche", "Carrera", 15, 675000, "BD51SMR");
        ArrayList uwiMotors = new ArrayList();

        uwiMotors.add(v1);
        uwiMotors.add(v2);
        uwiMotors.add(v3);
        uwiMotors.add(v4);
        uwiMotors.add(v5);
        System.out.println(v1.colors);
        System.out.println(v1.cost_price);
        System.out.println(v1.quantity);
        System.out.println(v1.registration_no);
        System.out.println(v1.selling_price);
        System.out.println(v1.year);

        for (int i = 0; i < uwiMotors.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(uwiMotors.get(i));


        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I am confused about the two constructors. Because if I initialize a reference variable to two constructors won't the values be changed? And how do I output the values from the Arraylist?
Do I have to override the `toString()` method? If yes then how do I do it?

Comment: You should call one constructor from the other instead of this.
Vehicle(String name, String model, int quantity, double cost_price, String registration_no) {
this(name, model, year, cost_price);
this.selling_price = cost_price;
        this.registration_no = registration_no;
    }
As for ArrayList output, iterate over the items using a for-loop (for example) and print your contents.

Comment: it says cannot reference year before supertype constructor has been called

Comment: Is this the real code you have? This ```public String tostring() {}``` cannot be compiled.

Comment: And if I loop over the arraylist it will just give me value in hashes because objects are stored in arraylists

Comment: @joragupra- I have not yet written it. thats what I am confused for

Comment: Avoid index based gets, instead use for each loops - for (Vehicle vehicle : uwiMotors) - as implementation of `List` like `LinkedList` will scan the list repeatedly during a for (int i...) type of iteration

Comment: I have rolled this question back to an earlier version, as the later version overwrote the original question's context, and invalidated all the answers given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being let us ignore the bad coding practises in your code. I hope the following code is what you are looking for?

```
      for (int i = 0; i < uwiMotors.size(); i++) {
                    Vehicle vehicle  = (Vehicle)uwiMotors.get(i);
//                 System.out.println(vehicle.cost_price+","+vehicle.quantity);
System.out.println(vehicle);// If vehicle object overrides the toString method


                }
```

Comment: Avoid index based `get`s, instead use for each loops - `for (Vehicle vehicle : uwiMotors)` - as implementation of `List` like `LinkedList` will scan the list repeatedly during a `for (int i...)` type of iteration.

Comment: But it is not overriding the tostring method, is it?

Comment: I have edited my post for the toString method
@NickHolt I had ignored the coding practises for now...

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code. First you should read about [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). You get only the hashes on the console because you are telling Java to output an object. Since your object does not have a proper toString method it cannot know how the output should look like.

Three hints:

```
Vehicle(String name, String model, int year, double cost_price) {
   //as you have it above
}
//add year to this constructor
Vehicle(String name, String model, int year, int quantity, double cost_price, String registration_no) {
    this(name, model, year, cost_price);
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.selling_price = cost_price;
    this.registration_no = registration_no;
}
```

And:

```
@Override
public String toString() { //camelCase is important!
    return this.name + ", " + this.model; //adopt this part as you want it to
}
```

Finally:

```
    //Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2011, 250000);
    //you cannot call two different constructors
    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Ferrari", "Enzo", 2011, 6, 250000, "PK07LVD");
```

Comment: And how to print the output from toString method

Comment: @user3401693 Your original code is doing that fine. If you use a statement like `System.out.println(uwiMotors.get(i));` then Java will access the `toString()` method on the Vehicle object that is returned by `uwiMotors.get(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused about the two constructors. Because if I initialize a reference variable to two constructors won't the values be changed?

Yes, actually you are replacing the first object with a new one, thus the initialization of your v1-v5 can be reduced to the following:

```
Vehicle v1;
v1 = new Vehicle("Ferrari", "Enzo", 6, 250000, "PK07LVD");
Vehicle v2;
v2 = new Vehicle("Audi", "R8", 9, 550000, "ADDY104");
Vehicle v3;
v3 = new Vehicle("RangeRover", "Evoque", 3, 578000, "OHZ2692");
Vehicle v4;
v4 = new Vehicle("Lamborghine", "Aventador", 5, 980000, "BB03813");
Vehicle v5;
v5 = new Vehicle("Porsche", "Carrera", 15, 675000, "BD51SMR");
```

You should either write a new constructor where you can pass all the parameters you need to initialize or use one of the constructors and then the setters for what's left.

> And how do I output the values from the Arraylist? Do I have to override the toString() method? If yes then how do I do it?

There are many ways you can solve this. Overriding the toString would be the simplest. And here is how you would do that:

```
public String tostring() {
    return "name=" + this.name + ", model=" + this.model + ", cost_price=" + this.cost_price + ", year=" + this.year + ", quantity=" + this.quantity + selling_price=" + this.selling_price+ ", registration=" + registration;
}
```

Feel free to modify this to only include the fields you need.

And then you can loop trough your arraylist to write it so System.out like this:

```
for (Vehicles v : uwiMotors)
{
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will give you a list of 'hashes' (it's not actually the hash code) because that's what the default implementation of [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) does.

The basic layout of your code should be something like this (I've removed some fields to keep the length down and used Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to help with the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods):

```
public class Vehicle 
{
  private String name;
  private String model;
  private String registration;

  public Vehicle(String name, String model) 
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.model = model;
  }

  public Vehicle(String name, String model, String registration) 
  {
    this(name, model);
    this.registration = registration;
  }

  public String getName() 
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String getModel() 
  {
    return model;
  }

  public String getRegistration() 
  {
    return registration;
  }

  public String getRegistration() 
  {
    return registration;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    return this == obj || obj instanceof Vehicle &&
      new EqualsBuilder()
        .append(getName(), ((Vehicle)obj).getName())
        .append(getModel(), ((Vehicle)obj).getModel())
        .append(getRegistration(), ((Vehicle)obj).getRegistration())
        .isEquals();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
      .append(getName())
      .append(getModel())
      .append(getRegistration())
      .toHashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE)
      .append("name", getName())
      .append("model", getModel())
      .append("registration", getRegistration())
      .toString();
  }   
}
```

Comment: my constructors can't be changed. that is how the question is

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the constructors, just that this is an example of how one constructor should call another

Answer (score 0):

Yes the two constuctors will change the values of the variables, just simply because You simply will create new object and assign it to the variable. As @ Christian Kullmann wrote You should think about calling Your one constructor from the other using 'this( arg goes here)'

To print the Arraylist elements You simply what to iterate them in loop and print one by another (as You did). However in case of overwriting toString You simply write like this

```
public String toString(){
 return "some text";
}
```